# Wordpress + Custom Pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a wordpress based website which involves displaying Certain videos based on User interaction. eg. If a user is new to the site ( Detected with cookie) he will see 5 videos. But the user is coming to the site again, his earlier interaction or search will affect the  list of Videos he will see.

So in short we will have some business rules which will govern what to show based on earlier search , type of user ( Gender etc )

Can this be achieved in wordpress?

Comment: The users are not group users , they can be anyone who is coming to the site. They may be in thousands.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create something like this with [rolescoper](https://wordpress.org/plugins/role-scoper/) or [presspermit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/press-permit-core/) but I think you need to use some custom coding to set user groups to detect first time or multiple time visits.

Comment: Thanks Ray! What I want is something like Youtube Recommendations. Which work on Users earlier interactions views searches etc. Yes it will require custom coding but need to understand how to push custom coding on the wordpress display page. So showing a content on the post page depending on business rule.